# How to use "when" condition in ansible to filter output

Tags: ssh, ansible

So I just started using Ansible in less than a week. I have tried and read multiple posts on how to filter output. However, none seems to work. I am using Ansible version: ansible 2.9.6 and python version = 2.7.12 
See my sample playbook below

```
#This playbook checks if a Cisco Router supports SSH using Telnet 
- name: Checking If Cisco device Supports SSH
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:
    - name: Telnet to Device
      telnet:
        login_prompt: ": "
        prompts:
          - '[>#]'
        command:
          - show ip ssh | include SSH       
      register: result
    - name: Second Task
      debug:
        msg: "{{inventory_hostname}} does not support SSH !"
        when: not(result.stdout.find('SSH Enabled') != -1)
```

The expected result: Ansible will search through the output of the Router and Search for non-existence of string "SSH Enabled" in result.stdout as a cisco IOS will return "Invalid input" if it doesn't support that command. The playbook is to be run across all devices and i have a different playbook to enable SSH on all of them. See below output when i execute this playbook.

```
PLAYBOOK: CheckSSH.yml *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
1 plays in CheckSSH.yml

PLAY [Checking If Cisco device Supports SSH] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************
META: ran handlers

TASK [Telnet to Device] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /../CheckSSH.yml:8
changed: [XXXX_sw] => changed=true 
  output:
  - |-
    show ip ssh | include SSH
                      ^
    % Invalid input detected at '^' marker.

    XXXX_SW#

TASK [Second Task] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /.../CheckSSH.yml:17
fatal: [XXXX_sw]: FAILED! => 
  msg: 'Invalid options for debug: when'

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
XXXX_sw                   : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Can someone please explain whats going on. I only want to automatically know if my devices supports SSH.
I intend running this command on 200 devices. Furthermore, i intend using output filtering to run diagnostics accross different devices.

Update: I have also applied the recommendation. See new code here

```
---
#This playbook checks if a device supports SSH using Telnet 
#The device must support telnet first though
- name: Checking If Cisco device Supports SSH
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:
    - name: Telnet to Device
      telnet:
        login_prompt: ": "
        prompts:
          - '[>#]'
        command:
#          - terminal length 0
          - show ip ssh | include SSH       
      register: result

    - name: Second Task      
      debug:
        msg: "{{inventory_hostname}} does not support SSH !"
      when: result.stdout is not search('SSH Enabled')
```

But see the output i get

```
TASK [Second Task] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /etc/ansible/CheckSSH.yml:18
fatal: [xxxx]: FAILED! => 
  msg: |-
    The conditional check 'result.stdout is not search('SSH Enabled')' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (result.stdout is not search('SSH Enabled')): 'dict object' has no attribute 'stdout'

    The error appears to be in '/etc/ansible/CheckSSH.yml': line 18, column 7, but may
    be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

    The offending line appears to be:


        - name: Second Task
          ^ here
```

Comment: [wait_for_connection](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/wait_for_connection_module.html#wait-for-connection-waits-until-remote-system-is-reachable-usable) might a better option compared to the parsing of the telnet stuff.

Comment: Oh true. The only problem is there are 3 different scenarios.
1. The device does not support SSH 
2. The device supports SSH but its no RSA has been generated so it wont accept ssh requests.
3. The device supports SSH but there is an ACL blocking SSH requests from my host ip. 

However, telnet always works cos i know this across all devices on my network.

Comment: I see. Try the condition below. Mind the indentation.

Answer (score 1):

Try [testing strings](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-strings)

```
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ inventory_hostname }} does not support SSH !"
      when: result.stdout is not search('SSH Enabled')
```

Comment: ```
fatal: [xxxx]: FAILED! => 
  msg: 'Invalid options for debug: when'
```

Still not working

Answer (score -1):

This would also work, a slight variation to the `when` statement

```yaml
when: "'ssh enabled' not in (result.stdout | join(''))"
```